# Visual studio 2005 toolbox icons messed up

Tags: visual-studio-2005, icons, toolbox

My studio toolbox icons are all messed up.  Is there a way to fix them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have custom controls just reset the toolbox. Right-click on toolbox then click reset.

Here are a couple posts with some more discussion about the problem:
http://xman892.blogspot.com/2007/05/visual-studio-toolbox-icons-mess.html
and
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/99afde0e-80e9-4f11-996c-6433608398ca

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Export all you existing
   settings/customizations (minus the
   Toolbox settings)
2. Reset the entire Visual Studio
   environment back to one of the base
   options
3. Import the options saved earlier
   (you didn't export the Toolbox
   settings so this will stay as
   default)

Like so

1. Goto Tools > Import and Export
   settings > Export selected
   environment settings.
2. In the dialog check everything
   expect the 'Toolbox' option under
   the 'General' tree item. Continue to
   save this to a known location.
3. Goto Tools > Import and Export
   settings > Reset all settings. 
   Don't bother saving, just overwrite
   with whatever you want.
4. Goto Tools > Import and Export
   settings > Import selected
   environment settings and choose the
   file you exported to ealier on.

Answer (score 0):

Just close Visual Studio & remove the *.tbd files from the C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0 location and restart VS. It will resolve this issue.