# Issues with WPF controls and Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, wpf-controls

Installing WPF Controls onto a machine is a messy task.
I tested installation in various systems including VMs. Following are the issues I have seen.

1. Controls not installed in the VS Toolbox.
2. Controls are isntalled but, cannot be dragged-n-dropped onto the WPF Window
3. Duplicate entries in the Toolbox sometimes!

I do not know what is wrong with the ToolboxControlsInstaller package. It messes up the Toolbox all the time, well most of the times.

Any guidelines what is the best practices to install WPF controls?
Our customers are very annoyed with these Toolbox behaviors.

Any help is welcome!

Regars,

-Datte

Comment: Your customers are annoyed? Or your developers?

Answer (score 1):

Our customers were annoyed too.

So I wrote this tutorial article covering toolbox installation once and for all:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

The most convenient approach seems to be using the Toolbox Controls Installer (TCI) package already pre-installed in VS2010 and newer. This includes just adding a key in registry, i.e.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller\SampleControl, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3cc4c7b61201d46c
```

You can also specify a custom tab name.

If you don't have a custom installer for your components, wrapping the DLLs in a VSI or VSIX package may be convenient. The VSIX is more powerful, support quiet install, custom tab name and uninstallation, but only VS2010 or newer.

Be careful with registry + VS2012. I discussed how the registry should be updated for VS2012, or simply call:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs
```

and then

```
devenv.exe /Setup
```

To clear things up.

Sometimes one also have to clear the Toolbox cache (TBD files), which seems to be a quite evil thing!

Answer (score 0):

How do you install WPF controls into toolbox? However, these are all common issues with Visual Studio toolbox if you(or someone while installing other components) have done some mistakes in configuring. Refer the below links which has suggestions to avoid these issues.

Installing controls to VS 2010 procedure : [How to add my custom WPF control to the ToolBox by using the WPF ToolBox Control template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799262/how-to-add-my-custom-wpf-control-to-the-toolbox-by-using-the-wpf-toolbox-control/2829754#2829754)

Icons messed up issue : [Visual studio 2005 toolbox icons messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329999/visual-studio-2005-toolbox-icons-messed-up/2353459#2353459) (though this is not reported with VS 2010, this solution would work for VS 2010 also).